# Encountered value error when implementing Polynomial Linear Regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, spyder

Here is my code... I am using Python 3.x by Spyder. You can download the dataset from https://www.superdatascience.com/pages/machine-learning

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Mar  8 19:50:28 2020

@author: Anurag Nihal
"""

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1: 2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

"""# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

Since, We are talking for employee's career and a sensitive decision to take, we will take as much as info present and also not much of info is present."""

# Feature Scaling-Not required since we are taking the same linear regression library and it provides the same facility
"""from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)
sc_y = StandardScaler()
y_train = sc_y.fit_transform(y_train)"""

#Performing linear regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg=LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X,y)

#Performing polynomial regression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg=PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X_poly=poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
lin_reg_2=LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, y)

#Visualizing Linear Regression
plt.scatter(X, y, color='red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(X), color='green')
plt.title('truth or bluff (Linear Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position Level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

#Visualizing Polynomial Regression
plt.scatter(X, y, color='red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)), color='green')
plt.title('truth or bluff (Polynomial Linear Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position Level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()


#Predicting the salary required using Linear Regression
lin_reg.predict(6.5)

#Predicting the salary required using Polynomial Regression
lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(6.5))
```

But this is as same as the tutorial by Super Data Science and there it ran perfectly there.

Here is the error it showed. It showed the same for `lin_reg.predict(6.5)`

```
lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(6.5))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-127-37e3532bc52e>", line 1, in <module>
    lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(6.5))

  File "F:\Anaconda_three\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 553, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "F:\Anaconda_three\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 1465, in fit
    n_samples, n_features = check_array(X, accept_sparse=True).shape

  File "F:\Anaconda_three\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 514, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=6.5.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I am also uploading the tutorial image where it ran perfectly.
[image]

I am currently learning Polynomial Linear Regression and have recently switched over Python from C++. Kindly help me to solve the problem and if possible suggest how to make sure that these do not occur in a code.

After the suggestion from @maverickk6912, I did this and inserted between Visualizing Polynomial Regression and Predicting the salary using Linear Regression.

```
#Lets make an array.
X_arr=([6.5])
X_arr=np.reshape(X_arr,(1,-1))
X_arr
```

But, my question is-Why did the tutorial code run perfectly??

Comment: Could you let us know the shape of X_poly?

Comment: fit_transform of PolynomialFeatures expects a numpy array of size`[n_samples,n_features]`. So all you need to do is follow what the error trail tells you to do: `array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample`. Check out the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.fit_transform)

Comment: @maverick6912 X_poly has dimensions (10,4).

Comment: @maverick6912 I beg your pardon. But, can you please elaborate on the process you talked? I just wanted to pass on the 6.5 value for the function ```lin_reg_2``` and ```lin_reg```.

Comment: From what I can see in my implementation, the shape of X_poly should be (10,35).
So, now your model `lin_reg_2` is fitted on a data-set with 35 features.
Whereas over here:
`lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(6.5))` you are trying to fit the model on output of `fit_transform` of `poly_reg` which will give you `X_arr of size(1,4)`. So there will be a mismatch of dimensions to which your model was fitted and to what has been passed to it for prediction. So, this won't work.

Comment: As for the question **Why did the tutorial code run perfectly??** I'm not really sure because the documentation clearly states that the `PolynomialFeatures' fit_transform` requires a numpy array of `shape [n_samples,n_features]`. It is possible that it was possible in an earlier version of sklearn, but again not really sure.